# Read a scss file into a variable so I can loop thru it

Tags: sass, storybook, rollupjs, bit-src

So, in my Storybook project, I am bringing in a bitstrc style sheet that is a ".scss" file. It works fine. The issue comes into play cause I want to iterate over it and display color swatches. Anyone know how this is done?

Right now, by current build took is:
Rollup
Here is my config:

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import sass from "rollup-plugin-sass";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

import packageJson from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
   {
     file: packageJson.main,
     format: "cjs",
     sourcemap: true
   },
  {
    file: packageJson.module,
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: true
  }
],
plugins: [
  peerDepsExternal(),
  resolve(),
  commonjs(),
  typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
  sass({
    insert: true
  })
]
```

};

For context, here is my folder structure:

```
 Button/
    Button.tsx
    Button.scss // <- HERE I include my '@bit/someproject/colors.scss' file
    Button.stories.tsx
```

So, I can import "@bit..." just fine in my scss files. BUT I am having two issues.

1. How to allow my style to be included in my .stories file?

**IN MY BUTTON.STORIES file**
I am doing: Works fine, I have access to the styles.

```
  import "./Button.scss".
```

I want to do:

```
  const styles from import "./Button.scss";
```

1. IF and in addition to, if I can't import like so: "const styles from './Button.scss';
   Is there a way to get this into an object so I can iterate over it and display color swatches?

Button.stories

```
import '@bit/myfolder/colors.scss';
```

then... get those color variables and create the swatches.

Of course when I do, now:

```
const colors from '@bit/someproject/colors.scss'
```

colors is an object that looks like:

```
Object
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

NOTE:
I ended up modifying the 'main.js' in .storybook/ folder to the follow so now I use "import styles from './Button.scss'. I ditched the "import Button.scss".

BUT, I have NOT tried to look thru styles, but i imagine I could now...but I haven't tried. Doing this now:

```
webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /styles\//, /styles\//],
      use: [
        { loader: "style-loader" },
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            modules: {
              localIdentName: "[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
            },
          },
        },
        { loader: "sass-loader" },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
    },
      {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: [/styles\//],
      use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
          modules: false,
          importLoaders: true,
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
        {
          loader: `postcss-loader`,
          options: {
            options: {},
          }
        },
        'sass-loader',
    ],
  });
```

Comment: james, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up modifying my storybook webpack... i added what i ended up doing in my original post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The sass plugin you are using does not support CSS modules, use one that does support them such as [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-postcss) (it also supports sass).

Comment: yeah, I tried that... and still won't work. In fact, the file ".scss" can't be found even though its right in the same directory.. ala: import styles from './Button.scss'; says can't find Button.scss.....

Comment: Did you configure the extensions option?

Comment: i'm pretty sure I did... I'll try again. Worth a shot.

Comment: Edit: Have a look at https://florian.ec/blog/rollup-scss-css-modules/ , it seems with sass syntax you don't need to add the extension. Could also be a problem with plugin order, try moving postcss up.